# Firestore error 'Updating a non-existent query'

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Sorry for my poor English.

When executing code like the following, an error like the image appears.

```
@firebase/firestore: - "Firestore(5.5.0): FIRESTORE(5.5.0) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Updating a non-existent query"

@firebase/firestore: - "Firestore(5.5.0): INTERNAL UNHANDLED ERROR: "

Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: FIRESTORE(5.5.0) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Updating a non-exixtent query

Error: FIRESTORE(5.5.0) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Updating a non-existent query
```

[firestore_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CU9o3.png)

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
const dammyRef = db.collection('dammy');

dammyRef.where('num', '>=', 18).where('num', '<', 30).get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.data());
    })
  });
```

**However, this error occurs only when using iPhone's Safari or Chrome.
There is no error in Chrome on the PC version.**

The version of Firebase,
`"firebase": "^ 5.5.0",`

Please tell me the reason why this error occurs.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please add some part of the error to the question? in this way it will be easier for people with the same problem to find it!

Comment: Giulio Caccin, Thank you for your comment.I have written error contents.

Comment: having the same problem. In my case it only happens when i'm not debugging react-native application. When i turn the debug on the error goes away

Answer (score 1):

For me, this error occurred when I had an invalid data type as the third parameter of the Firestore 'where' query. Check your data type and make sure the value matches what is in the database.